# Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have below code in react js.

```
class Posts extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      {console.log('test')}
    );
  }
}
```

After running this code I get error which is

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

   8 |     return (
>  9 |       {console.log('test')}
     |       ^
  10 |     );
  11 |   }
  12 | }
```

UPDATE

wrapping it up with parent tag returns the same error

```
>  9 |       <div>
     |       ^
  10 |         {console.log('nothing')}
  11 |       </div>
```

UPDATE

here is the whole class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class Post extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log('test')}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    posts: state
  }
};

export default Post;
```

Comment: I think you're just missing a top level JSX tag.  Trying using just the parens (drop the curly braces) or wrapping it in a div.

Comment: @ChrisCovert check my updated question.

Comment: On babel's online transpiler, if I copy/paste your code then remove the '{' and '}' around console.log, the error disappears.  Same as what @dacre-denny said.  If that's not working for you, then we probably need more information

Comment: Thats the point. syntax is correct but still this same error.

Answer (score 19):

You always need to have a wrapping parent JSX tag when returning jsx. Since you don't have any jsx tags it's just invalid javascript. Should be:

```
class Posts extends Component {
  render() {
    return console.log('test')
  }
}
```

or if you want the jsx

```
class Posts extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {console.log('test')}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

edit (2020-1-19)

jsx now supports empty tags for parent closures:

```
class Posts extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        {console.log('test')}
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: wrapping that up is the same error. Nothing changed.

Comment: It's valid js: https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEAKD2EAuMCmAPJqB2ATGAwvALYAO82OS0A3gFDTQBOOuqTAFAJS0OPOokAVybZoHPv2gAeXAEsAbgD5JU2sAoR4IVADoQ8AOYcA5FmQmuAX1WNpAennLVXPjatA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=

Comment: Maybe you don't have JSX/babel/webpack/ installed?

Comment: I created app using `create-react-app` which has everything.

Comment: You might want to paste more code. Everything you've provided so far looks valid.

Comment: Yeah, that unexpected token error is exactly what I get when I disable react/jsx support. Would make sure your create-react-app is set up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

in react js You have to put a value in the attr.

an example that works

```
<option selected={this.props.info.gender == 0 ? 'selected' : ''} value='0'>men</option>
<option selected={this.props.info.gender == 1 ? 'selected' : ''} value='1'>female</option>
```

not working

```
<option {this.props.info.gender == 0 ? 'selected' : ''} value='0'>men</option>
<option {this.props.info.gender == 1 ? 'selected' : ''} value='1'>female</option>
```

Comment: using (===) instead (==)

Answer (score 0):

@Mehrdad Masoumi, have a big mistake, this true:

```
<option selected={this.props.info.gender == **1** ? 'selected' : ''} value='**1**'>men</option>
<option selected={this.props.info.gender == **0** ? 'selected' : ''} value='**0**'>female</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

@null use a callback that returns console.log.

Asin

```
() => console.log('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

mapStateToProps used by connect method of redux 
add console.log Before the return method

Answer (score 0):

**Ook let me explain something, if you are mapping your objects or anything and getting this parsing error then try to put your map code inside React Fragments (<>)**

Look at the example

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { CartContext } from "../context/Context";

const UserInterface = () => {
  const { loading, data } = CartContext();
  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  return (
    <>
      {!loading ? (
        data.map((e) => {
          return (
            <>
              <img
                src={e.imageUrl}
                style={{ width: "50px", height: "60px" }}
                alt="something wrong"
              />
              <h1>{e.colour}</h1>;
            </>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <h1>Still Loading ....</h1>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default UserInterface;
```