# Functional component error: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs

I can't understand why this is throwing an error.

I want to check if songs exist, them map over them, but I get an error.

```
export function SongsList({songs}) {
return (
    <div className="pa3">
      <h3>Your Songs: </h3>
      <ul>
        {songs && (
          {songs.Map(song => <li>{song.name}</li>)}
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I've done this many other times but now it's not working, any ideas?

Comment: Think about which parts of what you've posted are JSX, and which are regular JS. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/52998987/3001761.

Comment: map needs to have a lowercase m

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky that's true, but it's *not* why it's failing to parse; that would be a runtime type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

songs.Map (side note, m should be lower case) shouldn't be wrapped with {}. 
change:

```
   {songs && (
      {songs.Map(song => <li>{song.name}</li>)}
    )}
```

to:

```
{songs && (
  songs.map(song => <li>{song.name}</li>)
)}
```

And it will work.

---

**UPDATE**

What's the difference between the two code samples?

According to React Docs:

> You can put any valid [Javascript Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions) inside the curly braces in
>   JSX. For example, 2 + 2, user.firstName, or formatName(user) are all
>   valid JavaScript expressions.

You should note, JSX is an expression too:

> After compilation, JSX expressions become regular JavaScript function
>   calls and evaluate to JavaScript objects.

In the second code sample, we have a valid expression inside the curly braces:

```
{songs && (
  songs.map(song => <li>{song.name}</li>)
)}
```

we evaluate the expression to false if songs is null/undefined (false is a valid expression), or we evaluate JSX expression (which is also a valid expression). 
 
 
**Whats wrong with the first code sample?** 
 
we evaluate the expression to false if songs is null/undefined, just like before. 
But if songs is not null/undefined, we try to evaluate a weird creature:

```
  {songs.Map(song => <li>{song.name}</li>)}
```

The fact it's wrapped with curly braces tells react it's an object (and object are not valid as a React Child, but that's another thing).
Javascript objects should have structure of key/value (key is a string): *{key: value, ...}* 
Our object is not a valid object, it doesn't have the *key:value* pair syntax. 
That's not a valid javascript expression, and that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: thanks I had added the extra curly braces because the map was making it fail.. thx!

Comment: It might be useful to explain *why* this change matters

Comment: @jonrsharpe i added some explanation.