# Browser throwing TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am a newbie in React and making a todo application using it. For listing the todos entered by the user, I am trying to use the map to go through all the todos and have added a functionality to be able to remove any of the todos.

Here is my `Todos.js`:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {ListGroup, ListGroupItem} from 'reactstrap';
import {FaCheckDouble} from 'react-icons/fa';
import { TodoContext } from '../Context/TodoContext';
import { REMOVE_TODO } from '../Context/action.types';


const Todos = () => {
    const {todos, dispatch} = useContext(TodoContext);

    return(
        <ListGroup className="mt-5 mb-2 items">
            {todos.map(todo => (
                <ListGroupItem key={todo.id}> 
                    {todo.todoString}
                    <span 
                    className="float-right"
                    onClick={() => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: REMOVE_TODO,
                            payload: todo.id
                        })
                    }}
                    ><FaCheckDouble/></span>
                </ListGroupItem>
            ))}
        </ListGroup>
    )
}

export default Todos;
```

And here is my `App.js` (Updated `todo` to `todos`)

```
import React, {useReducer} from 'react';
import Container from "reactstrap/lib/Container";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import './App.css';

import {TodoContext} from './Context/TodoContext';
import todoReducer from "./Context/reducer";
import TodoForm from './Component/TodoForm';
import Todos from './Component/Todos';

const App = () => {
  const [todos, dispatch] = useReducer(todoReducer, [])
  return(
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{todos, dispatch}}>
      <Container fluid>
        <h1>
          Todo App with Context API
        </h1>
        <Todos/>
        <TodoForm/>
      </Container>
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default App;
```

The browser is throwing me the error: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

[image]

Comment: `<TodoContext.Provider value={{todo, dispatch}}>` vs `const {todos, dispatch} = useContext(TodoContext);` `todo` and `todos` is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that `todos` is an array and not undefined. `undefined.map()` obviously does not make sense. So make sure that is imported properly and you can actually do like `todos && todos.map()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common issue with React. Todos value is initially undefined, and you're trying to render it. You can check its value with [useEffect()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

You should do the following:

```
const Todos = () => {
const {todos, dispatch} = useContext(TodoContext);

return(
    <ListGroup className="mt-5 mb-2 items">
        {todos ? (
            {todos.map(todo => (
                <ListGroupItem key={todo.id}> 
                    {todo.todoString}
                    <span 
                        className="float-right"
                        onClick={() => {
                            dispatch({
                                type: REMOVE_TODO,
                                payload: todo.id
                            })
                        }}>
                        <FaCheckDouble/>
                    </span>
                </ListGroupItem>
            ))}
        ) : null}
    </ListGroup>
)}
```

What you are basically saying is: if todos has some value, render the todos.map, if not, render nothing.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Now it's throwing a compile error in the line `todos.map` with this code. `Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","`

Comment: In that line? It looks good to me... Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998987/parsing-error-unexpected-token-expected/52999023

Answer (score -1):

check todos value, if null through error: map not defined.